# Graphical representation of duals of n-simplices

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings

Is there any way to graphically represents the duals of n-simplices?
For example, I want to know how exactly duals of tetrahedrons arrange between themselves, i.e how many faces, volumes share the same link... etc

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it meets your request, but I think this is explained in Griffith & Harris, "Principles of Algebraic Geometry", in chapter 0, paragraph on Poincaré duality (page 53 and following pages).